# Can Chainlink time-based upkeep register multiple cron jobs in a single contract?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-automation

I have been trying to make a raffle platform with the Chainlink automation.

I can see the time-based upkeep can have only one cron job,
But when the raffles are created in the platform, each of them has different deadline to generate a random number with chainlink VRF.

Would you guys have any idea of how to register multiple cron jobs ?
or
any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to have a couple of values for the raffles, a `hasRun` boolean and a `runsAt` time.

You could create one automation job that checks all the raffles that haven't run and then runs them if they have met their `runsAt` time.

Alternatively, if you want a unique automation for each raffle, you should look into [registering the upkeeps programmatically](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/guides/register-upkeep-in-contract).